# iOS - FlipCamera Button - AVPreviewLayer

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, avfoundation, uistoryboard

I'm searching the image of the "flip camera" Button for iOS Devices. Can't find anything usefull as psd or similar.

Do I miss anything? Is it possible send a method to the previewLayer to show the flip button?

Can't see the tree in the forest...

something like that - but for use ( psd or bmp without compression, noise etc. ):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [iOS Artwork Extractor](https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor) to get images like that. The one you're looking for is called `PLCameraToggleIcon` (the background images are `PLCameraOverlayButton` and `PLCameraOverlayButtonPressed`).